# How to add a Class using EditorFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Razor to create some HTML for a View.

Using this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Razor generates this HTML:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The User Email must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The User Email field is required." id="UserEmail" name="UserEmail" type="email" value="">
```

---

Please note  `class="text-box single-line"`

I need instead to have instead `class="form-control"`

What am I doing wrong here and how to fix it?

---

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Common_Annotations_CharactersLong", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Account_Register_UserEmail", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Account_Register_ConfirmEmail", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Compare("UserEmail", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Account_Register_ConfirmEmailErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string ConfirmEmail{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, basically, in the view using:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor()
```

and add:

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
```

in the model.

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Common_Annotations_CharactersLong", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), MinimumLength = 6)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Account_Register_UserEmail", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Account_Register_ConfirmEmail", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Compare("UserEmail", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Account_Register_ConfirmEmailErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string ConfirmEmail{ get; set; }



<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```